# Wordpress Ajax Login Error Message

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, authentication

I'm trying to develop a login ajax form for wordpress. Seems that the plugin works fine. If I insert correct username and password the login works correctly and display the correct message, then redirect to the correct page, but If I insert incorrect value for username and password nothing happen and the error message doesn't appear.

Seems that the function is_wp_error do not echo the error.

Do you have any idea why? Below my code

Thanks in adv.

PHP

```
function ajax_login_init(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-login', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ajax.login.js', array( 'jquery' ) , $ver , true );
wp_localize_script('ajax-login', 'loginajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), ) );
// Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_met_login_member', 'met_login_member' );
}

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');

}

function met_login_member() {
    $user_login     = $_POST['met_user_login']; 
    $user_pass      = $_POST['met_user_pass'];

    if( !check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'login-security', false) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Session token has expired, please reload the page and try again', 'met').'</div>'));
    }

    else if( empty($user_login) || empty($user_pass) ){
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Please fill all form fields', 'met').'</div>'));
    } else { // Now we can insert this account

        $creds = array();
       $creds['user_login'] = $user_login;
       $creds['user_password'] = $user_pass;
       $creds['remember'] = true;
       $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

        if( is_wp_error($user) ) {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$user->get_error_message().'</div>'));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-success">'.__('Login successful, reloading page...', 'met').'</div>'));
        }
    }

    die();
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="user-modal">

        <div class="user-modal-container">

            <ul class="switcher">

                <li><span><?php _e('Sign in', 'met'); ?></span></li>

                <li><span><?php _e('New Account', 'met'); ?></span></li>

            </ul>

            <div class="modal-login">

                <form id="login-form" class="modal-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="post" />

                    <p class="fieldset">

                        <label class="image-replace email" for="signin-email"><?php _e('Username', 'met'); ?></label>

                        <input id="user-login" class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="text" name="met_user_login" placeholder="<?php _e('Username', 'met'); ?>" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" required />

                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">

                        <label class="image-replace password" for="signin-password"><?php _e('Password', 'met'); ?></label>

                        <input id="user-pass" class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="password" name="met_user_pass" placeholder="<?php _e('Password', 'met'); ?>" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" required />

                        <span class="show-password"><?php _e('Show', 'met'); ?></span>

                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">

                        <label class="checkbox" for="rememberme">

                            <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90"><?php _e('Remember me', 'met'); ?>

                        </label>

                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">

                        <button id="wp-submit" class="full-width" data-loading-text="<?php _e('Loading...', 'met') ?>" type="submit"><?php _e('Sign In', 'met'); ?></button>

                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="met_login_member" />

                    </p>

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'login-security' ); ?>

                </form>

                <div class="errors"></div>

                <p class="modal-form-bottom-message"><span><?php _e('Lost your password?', 'met'); ?></span></p>

            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post(loginajax.ajaxurl, $('#login-form').serialize(), function(data) {

        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

        $('.modal-login .errors').html(obj.message);

        if(obj.error === false) {
            window.location.reload(true);
        } else if(obj.error === true) {
            $('.alert-danger').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).hide();});
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the die() function after echoing each message? -- I've elaborated your function a bit, please check the answer and let me know if you have any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're heading in the right direction. I've made a few changes to your code in order to fill up some gaps. It is highly recommended to sanitize all data collected from `$POST` when submitting sensitive (or any) data in WordPress.

Also, we're verifying the collected credentials with a simple check for the existence of a username or email, and if the check is ok, we define the user data needed for authenticating the user on success login, who'd also be logged in to the admin dashboard when accessing `/wp-admin/` directly. We do this by clearing out any old authentication cookies and setting up new ones for the current user.

Although there's nothing new going on here, those steps have proven to diminish most common issues when authenticating users through Ajax in WordPress.

I've tested the function and it seems to have no issues with the error messages being thrown by `is_wp_error()`. Additionally, I've added an optional simple way for catching the most common error messages and then customize those. I hope it gets you advancing with it!

```
function met_login_member() {

// First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
if( !check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'login-security' ) ) {

    echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Session token has expired, please reload the page and try again', 'met').'</div>'));

    die();

}

// Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign the user on
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login']    = !empty( $_POST['met_user_login'] ) ? sanitize_user( trim($_POST['met_user_login']) ) : NULL; 
$creds['user_password'] = !empty( $_POST['met_user_pass'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( trim($_POST['met_user_pass']) ) : NULL; 
$creds['remember'] = true;

// Pass login details through wp_signon()
// wp_signon() accepts an optional boolean parameter false OR true, whether to use a secure cookie in case of running a website over SSL.
$user_creds = wp_signon( $creds, false );

$user_login     = (string) sanitize_user( $_POST['met_user_login'] );
$user_pass      = (string) sanitize_text_field( trim($_POST['met_user_pass']) );

// ---- CHECK IF USERNAME OR EMAIL EXISTS ---- //
if (username_exists($user_login)) {

    $user_exists = (bool)   true;
    $user        = (object) get_user_by('login', $user_login);

} elseif (email_exists($user_login)) {

    $user_exists = (bool)   true;
    $user        = (object) get_user_by('email', $user_login);

} else {

    $error = new WP_Error( 'no_user_found', 'Username or Email was not found, please try again', 'Page Data' );

    //echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Username or Email was not found, please try again', 'met').'</div>') );
    //die();

} // end else

if ($user_exists === (bool) true) {

    // Define user data

    $user_id = $user->ID;
    $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);

    $username = $user_data->user_login;
    $userpass = $user_data->user_pass;

}

// ---- CHECK FOR EMPTY / INCORRECT DATA  ---- //
if( empty( $user_login ) && empty( $user_pass ) ){

    echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('The username and password cannot be empty', 'met').'</div>') );
    die();

} elseif ( is_wp_error( $user_signon ) ) {

    echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$user_signon->get_error_message().'</div>') );
    die();

    // Optionally catch & customize error messages

    // $signon_errors = $user_creds->get_error_codes();

    // if ( in_array( 'invalid_username', $signon_errors ) ) {
    //     echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Wrong username or email', 'met').'</div>') );
    //     die();    

    // } elseif ( in_array( 'empty_username', $signon_errors ) ) {
    //     echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('The username or email cannot be empty', 'met').'</div>') );
    //     die();

    // } elseif ( in_array( 'empty_password', $signon_errors ) ) {
    //     echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('The password field cannot be empty', 'met').'</div>') );
    //     die();

    // } elseif ( in_array( 'incorrect_password', $signon_errors ) ) {
    //     echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Wrong password', 'met').'</div>') );
    //     die();   

    // } else {
    //     echo json_encode( array( 'error' => true, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.__('Wrong username or password', 'met').'</div>') );
    //     die();

    // }

} else {

    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $username );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );

    echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'message'=> '<div class="alert alert-success">'.__('Login successful, reloading page...', 'met').'</div>'));

    die();

}

    die();

}
```